# Bootstrap popover on Android disappears after page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I have a question about bootstrap popover - javascript plugin. 
Popover has got text input inside, and when viewing this page on normal browser, I can click on this input and enter data.

But in android, when I open popover and click input, the keyboard appears but popover disappers.

On iOS popover works as expected, but on Android it dissapears.
My code is generic, and simple:

```
$('.logMe').popover({
            html: true,
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: function() {
                return $('#login').parent().html();
            }
        })
```

Thank You for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug.  The current workaround is a listener that will close it.  Something like this:

```
$('*').bind('touchend', function(e){
   if ($(e.target).attr('rel') !== 'tooltip' && ($('div.tooltip.in').length > 0)){
        $('[rel=tooltip]').mouseleave();
        e.stopPropagation();
   } else {
        $(e.target).mouseenter();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   $(window).refreshPosition();
});
```